# Alphabetically sorting by taxonomy name

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type with a taxonomy term entity reference tagged to it. I am trying to make a view that lists all nodes of this content type but I want the sorting to be alphabetical based on the taxonomy term tagged rather than by the node title.

It sounds simple in my head. I simply put in the Field of the taxonomy entity reference under "sort" in the view and set it to be ascending order. But what actually ends up happening is that the content is now sorted by the Taxonomy Term ID rather than the Name of the term.

I then tried to use a relationship of taxonomy term referenced from the field, then another for content using that taxonomy field and applied the relationship to the field under "Sort" but that ended up making the list looking even more wonky with duplicates of the same node multiple times.

Is it possible to sort by taxonomy name rather than by ID?